Which quantum chemistry codes have the capability use point charges in a QM/MM setting?
I came across a few examples like:

NWchem : QM/MM Bq charges
PySCF : QM/MM with MM charges
GPAW : External Point charge potential

I wanted to know of other code examples, which had the same capabilities.
